# ¿Como puedo mejorar este código?

Tags: php, sql

Como puedo mejorar este código para que el `while` no este dentro de cada case `switch`, esto tendría muchos case, y creo que no es la mejor forma para poner el `while` dentro de cada case, el problema es que cada consulta arroja columnas diferentes, es decir en numero, la primera 11, la segunda 1, sino me sería más fácil poner el `while` al final y después un `row[0]` si fuese solo una columna

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

if ( $_POST["opciones"] != ""){

    switch ($_POST["opciones"]){
        case "1nombreUser":

            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `tblusuarios`";

            //Consulta
            $results = $conn->query($consulta);
            print '<table border="1">';

            while($row = $results->fetch_row()){
                print'<tr>';
                    print'<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';
                print '</tr>';
            }

            print '</table>';
        break;
        case "2saldMaxM":
            $consulta="SELECT compania, COUNT(compania) AS PorCompania
                FROM `tblusuarios`";
        //Consulta
           $results=$conn->query($consulta);
           print '<table border="1">';

           while($row=$results->fetch_row()){
            print'<tr>';
               print'<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';
               print'<td>'.$row[1].'</td>';
            print '</tr>';
           }
          print '</table>';
        break;

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: La consulta que has puesto siempre debe devolverte el mismo número de campos. Puedes añadir otro caso para que veamos que quieres hacer? Con lo que tienes hasta ahora no te haría falta ni el if, ni el switch ni el case

Comment: ya esta actualizado, el caso es que hay mucho mas case, y lo que no quiero es meter en cada case el while, no se como lo puedo mejorar, por que cuando lo pongo afuera,  tendría que poner las 11 columnas de $row[], y al no mostrar nada en alguna consulta estaría indefinidas y con  ocupando espacio en la tabla innecesario

Comment: me saldría este error Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql\resultado.php on line 23

Comment: Mostranos que intentaste.. porque con ese ejemplo te diria que sacarlo solo embarraria el codigo mas... tendrias un solo while, pero if para controlar que campos mostrar y cuales no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basandome en el ejemplo basico que tienes, y suponiendo que TODAS las consultas son del mismo tipo, sin utilizar mas parametros (no hay WHERE ni ORDER u otros en tus consultas) yo simplificaria el codigo de la siguiente manera:

1.- creo un array con clave el valor posible de $_POST, y como valor la consulta.

2.- Despues comprobamos si el $_POST esta entre los valores de clave de dicho array, si es asi existe la consulta, sino damos un error.

3.- En caso de existir, cojemos la query correspondiente, y la procesamos para presentar los valores en la tabla.

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');

$queries = [
    "1nombreUser" => "SELECT * FROM `tblusuarios`",
    "2saldMaxM"   => "SELECT compania, COUNT(compania) AS PorCompania FROM `tblusuarios`",
];

$opcion = $_POST["opciones"];

if(in_array($opcion, array_keys($queries))) {
    //la consulta esta entre las aceptadas
    $consulta = $queries[$opcion];
    $results = $conn->query($consulta);
    print '<table border="1">';
    while($row = $results->fetch_row()){
        print'<tr>';
        print'<td>'.$row[0].'</td>';
        print '</tr>';
    }
    print '</table>';

} else {
    echo "ERROR: parametro no reconocido: '$opcion'";
}
```

De esta manera, seria mas sencillo añadir queries en tu aplicacion, solo tendrias que añadir la linea en el array $queries con la clave que te interese llevar en el post, y la consulta asociada.

**NOTA:**
no es muy correcto utilizar el mismo archivo para resolver lo mismo. Deberias empezar a plantearte utilizar MVC, y aplicar patrones de diseño para separar vista, modelo y controlador. Cada Query deberia gestionarse en su propio modelo, tu controlador deberia responder unicamente a un valor (tendrias varios controladores) y la vista deberia procesarse separada de los resultados obtenidos con el controlador.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación,  su código me da un error da en " $consulta = $queries[$opcion]; " no se espera el ;

Comment: cierto. Falta un parentesis en el if primero. Te lo corrijo